# BitBucket Deploy to Google Cloud appEngine could not find file Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, bitbucket-pipelines

I have .yml file for pipline of django the code for deploye is

```
- pipe: atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy:0.7.3
          variables:
            KEY_FILE: $KEY_FILE
            PROJECT: $PROJECT
            DEPLOYABLES: 'realpars_platform/app.yaml'
            VERSION: '${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}'
            PROMOTE: 'true'
            STOP_PREVIOUS_VERSION: 'true'
            EXTRA_ARGS: '--verbosity=debug --quiet'
```

But when i run this Error showes.

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/realpars_platform/app.yaml] does not exist.
✖ Deployment failed.

Comment: You need to make sure you specify the correct path to your `app.yaml` in the `DEPLOYABLES`. By looking at the error, it seems like the path that was specified doesn't lead to the `yaml` file.

Comment: Exactly i set my app.yaml on root of my project the folder of project is realpars_platform as you can see here. so my question is what the correct path?

Comment: Cloud you verify if your .yaml is located at `/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/realpars_platform/app.yaml`?